# Add a new line of total sales report to exported csv

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, export-to-csv

My code currently fetches total sales and sums the amount and then i export it into csv but i need a way to add another line in the exported csv where it shows the grand total of all users SUM(amount)?

Could someone here show me how could this be done please?

my code is

```
$m =$_REQUEST['m'];
$y =$_REQUEST['y'];
$date = "$y-$m";
$filename = "data.csv";
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="sales-report-'.$date.'.csv"');
$qry = "SELECT poster_name AS USER, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_SALES, SUM(amount) AS SUM_TOTAL, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %M') AS MONTH FROM details WHERE status = 'Sale' AND date LIKE '%".$date."%' GROUP BY poster_name";
$stmt = $db->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute();   

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = 0;
foreach ($rows as $line) { 
    if ($count == 0) {
        fputcsv($output, array_keys($line));
    }
    fputcsv($output, array_values($line));
    $count++;
}
fpassthru($output);
```

Really appreciate your help and inputs

Comment: You could just add `WITH ROLLUP` to your query...

Comment: @Nick can you please help out i have no clue on how to do it

Comment: Just add `WITH ROLLUP` to the end of your query (after `GROUP BY poster_name`) and you will get an extra row of results which will have the grand total in the `SUM_TOTAL` field.

Comment: @Nick thank you sooooo much reall appreciate it :)